# Problem with addEventListener to the button

Tags: javascript, dom, addeventlistener

I am creating a simple random user app that every time that the button is clicked, it will show the new user information, my next button doesn't work, i have no idea what i am doing wrong but i think I'm calling the button even before The DOM loads.

```
const apiUrl = `https://randomuser.me/api`;
const nextBtn = document.querySelector('button');



async function getUser(){

    const res = await fetch(apiUrl);
    const data = await res.json();
    console.log(data.results[0]);
    let results = data.results[0];
    displayUser(results)
}

function displayUser(results){

const userContainer = document.createElement('div');
userContainer.classList.add('user-container');
userContainer.innerHTML = `

<img src="${results.picture.large}" alt="">
        <div class="title">
            <h3>${results.name.first}</h3>
            <h3>${results.name.last}</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="info">
            <h3>${results.location.street.number + ' ' +results.location.street.name}</h3>
            <h3>${results.phone}</h3> 
            <h3>${results.email}</h3>
        </div>
        <button>Next User</button>
       
`;

document.body.appendChild(userContainer);
}

getUser();

nextBtn.addEventListener('click', getUser);
```

Comment: You expect to find the button before it is added to the page? `const nextBtn = document.querySelector('button'); console.log(nextBtn);` I am sure there is an error message in your console. You should looking for the button after you create it.

Comment: @Elnatanvazana there is no array....

Comment: You are selecting the button before the button is created. Try to move nextBtn declaration after you append userContainer to the body

Comment: `const nextBtn = document.querySelector('button'); ... if (nextBtn == null) /* not loaded yet */`

Comment: @Elnatanvazana AFAIK `querySelector` returns only one element (or null). It's `querySelectorAll` who returns a `NodeList`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind the event to the button when you create the button. The code does not keep looking for buttons to be added and add events to it.

```js
function add() {
  const userContainer = document.createElement('div');
  userContainer.classList.add('user-container');
  userContainer.innerHTML = `<button>Add</button>`;
  userContainer.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', add);
  document.body.append(userContainer);

}
add();
```